# Strange error in storyboard for custom control

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ibdesignable

This is the error:

```
Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: IB Designables: Failed to update auto layout status: The agent raised a "NSInternalInconsistencyException" exception: could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier WalletCurrencyCollectionCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard
```

I have wallet control in storyboard [image]

Wallet control has 4 cells in UICOllectionView , but it gives this error in storyboard (but when I launch code, everything is OK, it just gives error in storyboard). But if I set number of cells = 0 , it works fine, so the problem is in the collection view cell

Here is the structure of the cell

[image]

Here is the structure of wallet control

[image]

Here is the code of wallet control:

```
import UIKit

class WalletCurrencyCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var labelAccount: UILabel!

}

@IBDesignable class WalletControl: UIView, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,     UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
@IBOutlet var labelInYourAccount: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var labelOtherAccounts: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var collectionViewMain: UICollectionView!

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

    setup()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setup()
}

func setup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight ,.FlexibleWidth]
    addSubview(view)

    // localizations
    labelInYourAccount.text = "wallet_label_inYourAccount".localized
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    // register nib
    let collectionCellNib = UINib(nibName: "WalletCurrencyCollectionCell", bundle: nil)
    collectionViewMain.registerNib(collectionCellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "WalletCurrencyCollectionCell")

}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "WalletControl", bundle: bundle)
    view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
}

override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
//        return CGSizeMake(200, labelSuper.maxY + 10)
    let sizeOfView = viewContainerToMesherSize.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    return sizeOfView
}

// MARK: - Collection view

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // test
    return 4
}

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("WalletCurrencyCollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! WalletCurrencyCollectionCell

    // fill with information

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.widthMy
    return CGSizeMake(width, 100)
}
}
```

So I don't understand why I have this error in storyboard about nib, because I register nib. And after app launch everything is ok. What can I do with this storyboard error (the problem is in UICollectionView, because if I set number of cell = 0 everything is OK)?

Comment: class is setup in interface builder also?

Comment: if you are about WalletControl, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by calculating count of cells using server responce (I return 0 if there were no server responce about wallet accounts), so in this case storyboard always thinks that I have 0 cell and I don't have any warnings, and when I launch application everything is still OK, because I just properly display cells in UICollectionView

```
func help_getArrayOfUserCurrencyAccounts() -> [SCurrencyAccount] {
        if let currentUser = ApiManager.sharedInstance.userService_currentUser {
            return currentUser.arrayCurrencyAccounts
        }
        else {
            return [SCurrencyAccount]()
        }
    }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let realAccountsCount = help_getArrayOfUserCurrencyAccounts().count
        if realAccountsCount > 0 {
            if realAccountsCount == 1 {
                return realAccountsCount
            }
            else {
                return realAccountsCount + 1 // so we can scroll through accounts
            }
        }
        else {
            return 0
        }
    }
```